# How do I gunzip to a particular directory?

Tags: gzip, archive

I have `.gz` file like `BIG5.gz`. I want to gunzip this `.gz` file to the directory `BIG5`.

This did not work:

```
gunzip -c BIG5.gz > /BIG5
```

Comment: You're trying to unpack existing archive and put files in specific folder. In order to do that, you need to specify that you want to decompress using `-d` flag.

Comment: I have tried but didn't work.                                                                                      
$gunzip BIG5.gz -d BIG5/
error: gzip: BIG5 already exists; do you wish to overwrite (y or n)?

Comment: You probably created `/BIG5` with your initial command, so it is a file containing the stuff from your archive.  
According to the manpage, `-d` is just decompress.

Comment: In a gzip archive, you only have one file, not multiple files, so extracting into a directory does not really make sense. If you want to place it somewhere specific, create the directory (`mkdir /BIG5`) and then extract the files into a file in there (`gunzip -c BIG5.gz > /BIG5/yourfile`).

Comment: Related info: The `>` writes the output of a command into a file, never to a directory. So whatever is right of `>` will be a file.

Comment: Ya i know gzip archive have only one file but i have a requirement to put this file in folder with same name as gzip file.

Answer (score 3):

This should work on gz:

```
tar xvzf /dir/to/file.tar.gz -C /dir/to/output/
```

Comment: Only works if its a compressed tar file

Answer (score 2):

You can not provide a location to put the file directly. The easiest way is probably this:

```
mkdir -p /BIG5 && gunzip -c BIG5.gz > /BIG5/file
```

This will create the directory `/BIG5` if it does not exist, and then extract the file to that directory, to a file called `file`.

You need to replace `file` with the name  you want the extracted file to have.

This will fail when `/BIG5` is an already existing file, but succeed if it is present and it is a directory.